# Excel get the last / 2nd last / 3 last in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

right now I'm looking formula how to solve this in work.
Thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2WLG.png)
[image]

Comment: Please add a description of your problem.

Comment: Use FilterXML() with TextJoin() function. What is your excel version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `TEXTJOIN()` then try `FILTERXML()` with `TEXTJOIN()` like

Put in `P2` cell then drag down and across.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$B2:$O2)&"</s></t>","//s[last()-"&3-COLUMNS($A$1:A$1) &"]")
```

Put in `S2` cell then drag down and across.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF($B2:$O2<>"",$B$1:$O$1,""))&"</s></t>","//s[last()-"&3-COLUMNS($A$1:A$1) &"]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @harun24HR it's workable  ^ _ ^ would you mind to explain more detail ?

Comment: Ok. I will make an explanation of formulas. If it works then please tick mark the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use these 2 formulas.

In P2 and copied across and down to P2:R2.

```
=INDEX($B2:$O2,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($1:$14)/SIGN(LEN($B2:$O2)),19-COLUMN()))
```

In S2 and copied across and down to S2:U2.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$O$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($1:$14)/SIGN(LEN($B2:$O2)),22-COLUMN()))
```

They both use the `LARGE` function of `AGGREGRATE` with the option to ignore the errors returned by `COLUMN($1:$14)/SIGN(LEN($B2:$O2)`.

You could also use `FILTERXML` to get the values, not sure how to get the dates using that method.

Here's an example using FILTERXML that gets the value for Last-2.

```
=FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE,B2:O2),",","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y[last()-2]")
```

To get Last-1 you would change `last()-2` to `last()-1` and to get Last you would use `last()`.

Comment: You can have a look on my answer to return dates using `FILTERXML()` and `TEXTJOIN()`.